# How to configure react-native-router-flux android back history?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I have this react native app using `react-native-router-flux` for navigation config and stages, the thing is that I can't fully understand how to setup the android history so the back button is functional.

This is my view hierarchy:

```
<Router>
 <Stack hideNavBar key="root"> 
    <Scene back key="mainMenu" component={MainMenu}/>
    <Scene key="about" component={About}/>
    //... and so on
</Router>
```

But If I press back button after presenting a view with an action, for example:

```
Actions.about();
```

and inside about view I press back android button, I get the following error message:

```
"undefined is not an object (evaluating that.props.navigation.navigate)"
```

I really don't know what Im doing wrong. Please anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move the screen back, you can solve it with a simple command.

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove()
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    // go back (i.e. pop the current screen off the nav stack)
    Actions.pop()
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: The thing is that android back button is giving me the error. In my UI Im already using `Actions.pop()` to return to previous views.

Comment: No, no error when using `pop()`. Error occurs when I press back button on android only.

Comment: @KarloA.López You mean the back button Android's only? is it device backButton?

Comment: yes, that exactly. I've tried to add some listeners but the error continues showing up!